# how to push a row depending on number Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

so im trying to create a form that once i put a number in qty it will push it a row depending on the qty i put how to achieve that? i trying to find a reference but i dont see any?

```
  <table formArrayName="displayArray">
     <thead>
     <tr>
     <th></th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     </table>
     <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let displayArray of displayArray.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
   <td>
  <input type="text" formCOntrol="DisplayRow" class="form-control" style="width:700px">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>



this.serialForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [0],
      qty: [''],
      displayArray: this.fb.array([{
        DisplayRow:['']
      }])
    })

 get displayArray():FormArray{
    return this.serialForm.get('displayArray') as FormArray;
  }
```

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz (or similar) so that we can reproduce it faster ? For web stuff, sharing stackblitz (or similar)  is much faster to reproduce than putting a piece of code here.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-9njzr5

Comment: What do you mean by "push a row" ? Do you want the row to move down by a certain height depending on qty ?

Comment: if i input in qty 6 the row will be 6 too

Answer (score 0):

Until Angular v6, the idea is to use Angular's two-way binding.

On typescript side, declare a variable `commonVar` that will store what you put in the forms.

On HTML side, change the input elements corresponding to QTY and ROW from:

```
<input ... />
```

To this:

```
<input ... [(ngModel)]="commonVar" />
```

---

For Angular v6+, the idea is to use the rxjs observable `valueChanges`, which is a property of the class `AbstractControl` (from which `FormControl` and `FormGroup` derive from). It emits the entire `FormGroup` object whenever an item in the forms is updated (either manually or programmatically).

You can subscribe to it in the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook of your component, for example.

For your case, it would be something like:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe({
      next: (changedForm) => {
        this.form.patchValue({ row: changedForm.qty });
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      },
      complete: () => {},
    });
  }
```

Comment: how to not use ngmodel?? igot this when i use ngModel

 It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName.
  Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with
  reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed
  in a future version of Angular.

  For more information on this, see our API docs here:
  https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that. I will add another answer for Angular v6+

Comment: @Steve Please, check my update for Angular v6+